# R - Compare performance of two types while controlling for interaction

Tags: r, statistics

I have been programming in R and have a dataset containing the results (succes or not) of two Machine Learning algorithms which have been tried out using different amounts of parameters. An example is provided below:

```
type success paramater_amount
a1     0       15639
a1     0       18623
a1     1       19875
a2     1       12513
a2     1       10256
a2     0       12548
```

I now want to compare both algorithms to see which one has the best overall performance. But there is a catch. It is known that the higher the parameter_amount, the higher the chances for success. When checking out the parameter amounts both algorithms were tested on, one can also notice that a1 has been tested with higher parameter amounts than a2 was. This would make simply counting the amount of successes of both algorithms unfair.

What would be a good approach to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an answer but without any guarantees on the truth of what I'm telling you. Indeed for more precisions you should give more informations on the algorithm and other. I also propose to migrate this question to cross-validate.

Indeed, your question is a statistical question. Because, in statistics, we search for sparcity. We prefer a simpler model than a very complex one at given performance because we are worried of over-fitting : https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/overfitting-regression-models/.

One way to do what you want is to compare the performance with respect to the complexity of the model like for this toy example :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
# number of estimation for each models
n <- 1000

performance_1 <- round(runif(n))
complexity_1 <- round(rnorm(n, mean = n, sd = 50))

performance_2 <- round(runif(n, min = 0, max = 0.6))
complexity_2 <- round(rnorm(n, mean = n, sd = 50))

df <- data.frame(performance = c(performance_1, performance_2),
                 complexity = c(complexity_1, complexity_2),
                 models = as.factor(c(rep(1, n), rep(2, n))))

temp <- df %>% group_by(complexity, models) %>% summarise(perf = sum(performance))

ggplot(temp, aes(x = complexity, y = perf, group = models, fill = models)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

It only works if you have many data points. Complexity for you is the number of parameters fitted. In that toy exemple, the first model seems a better because for each level of complexity it is better.